# How to declare a double ** from C with numpy.ndpointer for ctypes python call?

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I wonder howto use ndpointer for a double **.

Consider a matrix of vertex[100000][3] and a function in C like:

```
double dist(double **vertex)
```

To call this function from C, I need to create the following matrix of pointer:

```
  double **b=(double **)malloc(sizeof(double)*100000);
  for (i=0;i<100000;i++)
  {
      b[i]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
  }
```

If I use ctypes to call this dist function from python, I need to do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
vertex_np=np.reshape(np.random.randn(nb_millions*3e6),(nb_millions*1e6,3))
pt=ctypes.POINTER(ct.c_double)
vertex_pt= (pt*len(vertex_np))(*[row.ctypes.data_as(pt) for row in vertex_np])
result=lib.dist(ctypes.pointer(vertex_pt))
```

The problem is the loop to create the vertex_pt...

How can avoid this loop with the use of ndpointer from numpy.ctypeslib ?
[How to declare a pointer of pointer with numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer?]

thanks for help

-baco

**EDIT - BAD/LOW Solution:**

The only way I found to avoid this loop is to modify the declaration of dist with:

```
double dist(double (*vertex)[3])
```

and then I can use ndpointer in python code:

```
lib.dist.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ndim=2,shape=(100000,3))]
result=lib.dist(vertex_np)
```

Comment: `ndpointer` is factory for `_ndptr` subclasses. As a result type, an `_ndptr` provides an `__array_interface__` to create an array from a pointer. As an argument, an `_ndptr` checks the type, dtype, ndim, shape, and flags before returning `obj.ctypes`, which returns a `void *` from its `get_as_parameter` method.

Comment: so you mean that is not possible to create a pointer of pointer with the ndpointer class? I'm little confused...

Comment: Is `dist` your function or one your calling in some other library that expects a `double **`? It's an inconvenient way to handle a contiguous array.

Comment: `ndpointer` returns a subclass of `_ndptr`, which doesn't do what you want. You could make a similar type. The array of pointers still has to be initialized, though. It's not very meaningful as a result type, unless maybe you want to create a tuple of arrays.